# How to check vpn whether setup and vpn status in iOS device

Tags: ios, vpn

In my app project, I need to detect whether the VPN on iOS device is setup, and put the VPN information into log file. So wen can get more information to solve user's feedback troubles.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you properly, but you can try to use this 
loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler(_:) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEVPNManagerClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NEVPNManager/loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: